# Disable trackpad feedback? Don't want any tactile/haptic feedback when clicking

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, trackpad

Can I completely disable the haptic feedback from my 2015 MacBook Pro with Retina's trackpad?

I want to click without *any* kind of vibration/feedback.

Ideally it should feel like (as I imagine it would were this disabled) pressing onto a solid bit of metal. I.e. the case surrounding the trackpad.

Answer (score 3):

I have a 12" Macbook (2015) and a Macbook Pro (2017), both running MacOS 10.13.6. The 12" gives me the option for "Silent Clicking" in Trackpad Preferences. The MBP, however, does not give me this option (and I wish it did). So, while it does seem to be capable of being switched off, there does seem to be some hardware-specific aspect to it. Silent mode is nice... wish they all did it.

Comment: I currently have silent clicking enabled, but I still get haptic feedback.

Comment: Strange. There is a substantial difference on my 12" when I enable silent clicking. Basically, it did exactly what I expected - the hepatic engine seems to be off, but I still get the physical "click" of the trackpad mechanism itself, which is much more quiet than with hepatic feedback.

Comment: I want to get rid of the physical click. The "trackpad mechanism" of which you speak is haptic feedback. The actual "trackpad mechanism" is a capacitive touch screen, that doesn't need to vibrate at all.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I guess rather than "Silent Clicking", it would have been more accurate to call it "Muted Clicking". With that said, I did a (unscientific) test using an SPL meter app I had on my phone, and consistently measured a ~7 dB difference in the sound of a force click depending on whether the "Silent Clicking" mode was on or off. So, while it doesn't truly silence the click, it does make it noticeably quieter. I just wish it was an option on all models. The "Tap to click" option is truly silent, but you lose force click. But a silent force click would be pretty useless, IMHO.

Comment: I don't care _at all_  about the way it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's not possible to do using a "normal" way, it's restricted to the Service team only. Though it's possible ultimately, the motor probably needs software to tell it whenever to vibrate, it's just that the software is not accessible normally, I believe.

By the way, I current have the problerm, the Taptic motor stopped working but the 4 sensors still are working so I kind of using a "TRUE solid-state" trackpad, everything works except the Taptic, it's cool, I think it's the best "issue" you can ever get on your Mac, it feels great.

Comment: I'm extremely jealous

Comment: Haha, it is very comfortable once you get use to the issue, it's just that you have to get acquainted with the "brain-driven" gesture, knowing how hard to press enough to activate a click without "trying the press the touchpad" off the machine. 

Comment: Do you know if I can replicate? How did you end up breaking the taptic motor?

Comment: Just kidding but if you are serious with getting the "pristine" solid state trackpad, I think it's because there is something that damage the cable from the Taptic motor, as I have done a little bit research, an it turns out that the cable is located right beneath the touchpad surface (images from iFixit). If you are really serious about "breaking" your Mac, I think a piece of paper would have the thing done, but it's pricey to replace your part in case you regret, so be serious.

Comment: If you want to try the "feeling" first, it is much like you turn off the Vibration Accessibility on your iPhone that HAS 3D Touch, Haptic Touch would not be as effective and "real".

Comment: I didn't break it, it suddenly stopped working, I'm fine within the coverage of Apple Care but I am not sure if I will bring it to Apple, cause the feeling is so much comforting and, you know, "pristine" somehow, it's like Magic. Normal people would say I am clicking on a completely dead still surface and fly through my work.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly why I want to set my laptop up like that. I want that same feeling.

Comment: If you're Mac out of warranty and you are fully intentional, I think you could have someone open your Mac and disconnect the Taptic motor from something like the motherboard (I don't know exactly). Apple Genius would be able to do that but I think they'll not ever.

Comment: Or you can manually take a piece of paper and try to slip it back and forth in the gap between the trackpad and palm-rest (horizontally). But I'd say be careful about this, you are not going to know what you end up with, getting the privilege or destroyed your whole trackpad, and then have to replace WHOLE trackpad, that's pricey hey. Because there are other parts below the surface, not just the motor.

Comment: I am telling you that my motor has worked back, so just open it if you want to have the feeling, don't use the paper cause you do not know what the paper will break, maybe it'll not be your motor haha

Answer (score -2):

You can't.  It's not a software controlled click, it's hardware.  You can use the "tap to click" gesture rather than a physical click.  Enable it in System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click tab.

Credit: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3655934?start=0&tstart=0  @captfred

Comment: You have proof it's hardware? I don't think it is.

Comment: You're thinking of old MacBooks.  Starting in 2015, MBP's have haptic clicking.